# What are the possible values of $m^2 + n^2$?

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing

> Let $m,n \in \Bbb N$ with $m>n>1.$ If $m=n^2$ and $m^n - m = (m-n)!$ then what could be the possible values of $m^2+n^2$?

I found that one of the solutions is $m=9$ and $n=3$ so that $m^2+n^2 = 90.$ Is there any other solution to this problem? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much for your valuable time.

Comment: First of all, you can replace $m$ with $n^2$, and you will still find all the possible solutions. Your equation then becomes $n^{2n}-n^2=(n^2-n)!$

Comment: Yeah I know that. But what are the possibility for $n$ if it would satisfy the equation $n^{2n} - n^2 = (n^2 - n)!$?

Comment: \\begin{array}{cc}n&n^{2n}&(n^2-n)!+n^2\\
1&1 & 2\\
2&16 & 6\\
3&729 & 729\\
4&65536 & 479001616\\
5&9765625 & 2432902008176640025\end{array}  $(n^2 - n)!$ is growing much faster than $n^{2n}$

Comment: What did you do @miracle173?

Comment: @miracle173 Thank you very much, I though that both sides were of roughly the same magnitude, but I obviously was quite wrong there. Using induction, it should be possible to prove that the solution that math maniac found is the only one. The details will be pretty gory, I suppose...

Comment: It shouldn't be *that* gory: When you increase $n$ by 1, $n^{2n}$ grows by a factor $≈ e^2(n+1)^2$ (since $(1+1/n)^n ≈ e$), whereas $(n^2-n)!$ grows by a much bigger factor.

Answer (score 1):

If you graph $n^{2n}-n^2$ and $(n^2-n)!$ you see that they intersect at a low value and one more time way up, because $x^x$ grows slower than the $(x^2)!$ function.
[image]
At x = 3 there‘s a solution (which you mentioned) and at x = 1.463... (not an integer, so we don‘t care).

Now a proof for why the one function grows faster than the other:

$x^x = x*x*...*x*x$ **(x times)**

$(x^2)! = x^2*(x^2-1)*...*(x+1)$ **($x^2-x$ times)**  $*x*(x-1)*...*2*1$  **(x times)**

Because every term of the first $x^2-x$ terms is bigger than x, this inequality is true (for values of x bigger than 1): $(x^2)! > x^{x^2-x}$, which means that it grows faster than $x^x$. (The other terms don‘t matter when $n >> 0$)

So we can conclude there is only the one solution that you mentioned.

Comment: Could you please develop your argument after the expression of $(x^2)!$ ? I can't see how you can get $(x^2 -x)!$

Comment: As x grows bigger (or the limit as x goes to infinity) the term $x^2$ is growing much faster than x, which means we can ignore x, because it doesn‘t change how fast the function is growing.$$ $$ Example:$$$$ for $x=2$ $$x^2=2^2=4$$ $$x=2$$ for $x=20$ $$x^2=20^2=400$$ $$x=20$$

Comment: Sure, I agree that asymptotically there is no doubt that the red curve is above the blue one. But to *prove* (without knowing the relative shapes of the graphs) that *m=3* is the only possible integer solution, you need to know the actual (not  asymptotic)  "threshold" above which the red function is higher than the blue one . And this seems to be a messy affair. Of course, when the graphs are plotted, you can see that the curves are "regular" enough to be convinced that they do not intersect above the point corresponding to x=3.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find $k=n^4+n^2, n\in \mathbf N, n >1$, knowing that  $n^2(n^{2n-2}-1)=(n^2-n)!$ (@). Since this is a diophantine problem, it seems natural to try a $p$-adic approach. Recall that, given a prime $p$, the "$p$-adic valuation" $v_p$ on $\mathbf N\(0)$ is defined by $v_p(x)=a$ if $p^a$ is the maximal power of $p$ dividing $x$. Then   $v_p (k)=2v_p(n)+v_p(n^2+1). $ We'll distinguish two disjoint cases : (1) $p$ divides $n$, hence $v_p(k) = 2v_p(n)$ ; (2) $p$ does not divide $n$, in which case $v_p(k) =v_p (n^2+1)$. In all generality, this determines $k$ in function of $n$

It remains to take into account the additional condition (@), which is equivalent to the relation $2v_p(n)+ v_p (n^{2n-2}-1)=v_p((n^2-n)!)$ for all primes $p$. In case (1),  $v_p(LHS) = 2v_p(n)$ ; in case (2)  $v_p(LHS) =v_p (n^{2n-2}-1)=v_p(n^{n-1}-1)+v_p(n^{n-1}+1)$. To go further, it remains to compute $v_p(N!)$, with $N=n^2-n$, in function of $n$. First write $N$ in the $p$-adic scale, using successive euclidian divisions by $p$ to get $N=a_0+a_1 p+...+a_rp^r$, where the $a_j$ are integers s.t. $0\le a_j\le p-1$ for all $j$. Because $[N/p]=a_1+a_2p+...+a_rp^{r-1},...,[N/p^r]=a_r$, we get readily $v_p(N!)=a_1+(1+p)a_2+...+(1+p+...+p^{r-1})a_r$, whence $v_p(N!)=(N-s_N)/(p-1)$, with $s_N=a_0+a_1+...+a_r$, and our equation (@) will read $(N-s_N)/(p-1)=2v_p(n)$ in case (1), or $(N-s_N)/(p-1)=v_p(n^{2n-2}-1)$ in case (2). Summarizing, $v_p (k)=2v_p(n)=(N-s_N)/(p-1)$ in case (1), and $v_p (k)=v_p (n^2+1)= v_p(n^{n-1}-1)+v_p(n^{n-1}+1)=(N-s_N)/(p-1)$ in case (2). It is quite possible that these conditions are strong enough to allow no other solution than the one that you found experimentally for $p=3$. But one can't tell without explicitly computing the above development of $N=n^2-n.$